I also tried using code to get time phased cost out of Project 19 but keep getting the overflow 6 error
Here's the code that @Rachel provided:
Sub MSCostOutlay()
    Dim tsv As TimeScaleValue
    Dim tsvs As TimeScaleValues
    Dim t As Task

    For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
        t.Baseline9Cost = t.BaselineCost
        t.Baseline9Duration = Application.DateDifference(t.Start, t.Finish)
        Set tsvs = t.TimeScaleData((t.Start), t.Finish, pjTaskTimescaledBaseline9Cost, pjTimescaleDays, 1)
        For Each tsv In tsvs
            If ActiveProject.Calendar.Period(tsv.StartDate, tsv.EndDate).Working Then
                tsv = t.Baseline9Cost / (t.Baseline9Duration / (60 * 8))
            End If
        Next tsv
    Next t

End Sub

I changed the Cost5 field to BaselineCost as I wasn't using Cost5.
I have a MS Project19 schedule with ~ 1600 tasks and some inactive tasks. I've tried cutting down the size of the project to 200 tasks and deleted any Inactive tasks but it still gives me the Overflow 6 error. I've also tried to substitute (60*8) with 480 but no joy.
I suspect the overflow occurs at tsv = t.Baseline9Cost / (t.Baseline9Duration / (60 * 8)) but I haven't been able to find a way to increase the size of tsv.
Any help would be appreciated.
I'm expecting to get Cost data by task to use in an Excel program.

@John-project
Thanks for working with me on this topic. You not only answered my initial request, but you determined what my ultimate goal was and included code to facilitate the outcome so that I don't have to run numerous other code or manipulate the data between MS Project and Excel. This is going to make my life much better.
For anyone else looking for a solution to their coding issues, I would recommend explaining not only the code issue(s) but also explain what's your ultimate goal as I not only got my code answer, but a whole lot more.
